# How to change boolean value if checkbox is cheked?

Tags: html, angular

I would like to change a boolean value inside the component file with a simple checkbox. If it is not checked it should remain false, otherwise it should be true.

Component:

```
export class UsersComponent {
  public Personal: boolean = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Personal" [(ngModel)]="Personal"/>
    Personal
</label>
```

Comment: Your code already does it. Nothing has to be changed. It should also be noted there are multiple other methods to achieve it. Look into Angular reactive forms and Angular template driven forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added 2 way binding in html `[(ngModel)]="Personal"`, it should assign automatically

check via

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Personal" [(ngModel)]="Personal"/>
    {{Personal}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these to toggle the value of the Personal

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="Personal" (change)="mPersonal = !Personal" /> Checked + Change
    {{Personal}}
</label>
```

Correct For 2 way binding :

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Personal" [(ngModel)]="Personal" />
    {{Personal}}
</label>
```